# How do I make above-the-fold content load first on my website? (control the load order)

Tags: performance, pagespeed

My website for architectural visualization: http://www.greenshell3d.com

I noticed on the networking tab / incognito it takes 15 seconds or so to load the above-the-fold content. (most notably the image slideshow.)

Some of the images in the slideshow load at the very end instead of the beginning of the website load process. Now I understand the browser handles this order, but perhaps there is another way. As it stands, the bounce-rate is too high and I expect it is because of load time.

I've seen a jquery snippet on github that allows one to control the order of image loads - do you think this is a good option? I'd be glad to hear any opinions before investing the time to fix this.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You said you are interested in any opinions as well, so first some general thoughts: **There is no page fold.** The web that we produce content for exists in so many different screen sizes + resolutions that it’s impossible to say "The fold is below this big image!". Yes, Google changed the pagespeed insights tool to make people load stuff on top of the page first, but I think their wording there is really bad.

Now to your image loading issue:

The first thing I would recommend is to reduce the size of all the images. They seem to be around 280 - 300 kb per image and you have a few of them. Since there is a translucent overlay over them anyways you can probably get away with reducing the image quality without people noticing it (because they don’t see the image directly). Play around with the values here.

I would then look into optimizing the code for the slider to load the first image first, then the rest of the page and the other images asynchronously maybe after that. Another trick could be to increase the slide fade time from the first slide to other slides so the slider doesn’t change if the next image isn’t ready yet. You said you found a jQuery script to implement that, that’s where I’d start.

As a general guideline: the position of requests in the source code usually determines the load order of things on the page. If your images are requested by JavaScript at the end of the page, that lead to the images being loaded later than you want them to be loaded.